# Expanded Widget throws " RenderBox was not laid out" Exception

Tags: flutter

I'm new to flutter. I'm setting up an Expanded Widget which contains a ListView Widget. the Expanded Widget sits in a Column Widget. But running the code gives "RenderBox was not laid out" Exception. How do I fix the code?

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
      children: products
          .map(
            (element) => Card(
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(element)
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
          )
          .toList(),
    );
```

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child:   ProductControl(_addProduct),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Products(_products),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
```

error:

```
I/flutter ( 9914): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFlex#e84ab relayoutBoundary=up2 NEEDS-PAINT
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear to me. You gave 2 build method, which one is causing isuse?

Comment: it's the second one. The Product class is a ListView Widget.

Comment: You can post your `Products` class? To me it is working fine as of now.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Flexible` instead of `Expanded` when using it with `ListView` or `ScrollView`.

Comment: did it work? let me know if you still having issue.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Flexible or Try wrapping expanded in a container with fixed width and heigh

```
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              child:   ProductControl(_addProduct),
            ),
           container(
            width:300,//set as required
            height:300,
            child:  Expanded(
              child: Products(_products),
            ),
           ),
          ],
        );
      }
```